# Can macosx register an UTI with a dot in the extension?

Tags: macos, plist, file-extension, uti

I've read Apple's [Introduction to Uniform Type Identifiers Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319) and [Technical Q&A QA1587](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html)
 but there is no information on how to register an extension with a dot, like `filename.nimrod.cfg` where the extension is not just `.cfg` but `.nimrod.cfg`. The plist definition I'm using is the same as for single extensions:

```
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>org.nimrod-lang.cfg.nimrod</string>
        <key>UTTypeReferenceURL</key>
        <string>http://nimrod-lang.org/</string>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Nimrod configuration file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>public.text.icns</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
            <string>public.utf8-plain-text</string>
            <string>public.source-code</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>nimrod.cfg</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

However, when I debug preview one of these files the qlmanager tells me the file is not being registered:

```
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Users/gradha/Library/QuickLook/QuickLook reStructuredText copy.qlgenerator> for org.nimrod-lang.nim
[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator /Users/gradha/Library/QuickLook/QuickLook reStructuredText copy.qlgenerator> for org.nimrod-lang.cfg.nimrod
[DEBUG] Preview test for nakefile.nimrod.cfg -- file://localhost/Users/gradha/project/nimrod/ql-rest-nim/. Content type UTI: dyn.ah62d4rv4ge80g3xh
```

So it looks like the UTI is being registered, but the *double* extension not being correctly recognised. How can I make QuickLook detect these files properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, this is obvious. The UTI standard tells you that a period in the UTI string is a decider in the reverse-order chain of classes.

So --- It was parsed and used correctly. Don't have a period in your UTI parts. replace the with something else within the standard.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, the problem I have is with the dot in the file extension, not in the UTI parts. The log shows that QuickLook is going through the org.nimrod-lang.cfg.nimrod but the extension is not matching.

Comment: Because it uses the period to decide WHAT IS THE EXTENSION. Namely whatever is AFTER THE LAST PERIOD. Simply put, filename-extensions cannot have a dot inside them. UTI Parser will have one more component in the reverse-order-chain.

Comment: This counter argument is dumb. OP is aware that extension delimeter is with dot. The ask is if it's possible to register an extension that can contain dot. Seems answer is NO.